# Are ARC Welder packaged Android apps only available on Chrome OS?

Tags: google-chrome-os, google-chrome-arc

If I package an Android app with Google ARC Welder and distribute it through the Chrome Web Store, will it be available for Windows, Mac, Linux, or only for Chrome OS? If so, are there any news if that will change in future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ChromeOS only, as clearly stated at https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc :

> The App Runtime for Chrome (Beta), or ARC, lets you run your favorite Android apps on Chrome OS

There is no information about support for other platforms other than for development and initial testing at this time.

Comment: But you can use it on Win, Mac. Linux too - at least with the beta: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/run-instagram-your-desktop-via-arc-welder-kevin-mullett Does it mean that Google will roll out ARC to all platforms or is the ARC Welder only for developers to package the apps?

Comment: It is likely that only chrome OS distribution will be supported for the entirety of the Beta.